# Proof differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential

Let $g:C\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with the property $\exists A>0 \exists \alpha >1 \forall x\in C : |g(x)|\leq A\cdot|x|^\alpha$. $C$ is a circle with a radius radius $r>0$ with its center point in 0,0.

Now I want to proof, that $g$ is differentiable in $0$. Could you give me a hint, how I could solve this problem?

Comment: $C$ is a circle? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Assuming by $C$ you actually mean the disk of radius $r$, then you should write out the limit definition of the derivative, and check that this limit exists.

Comment: A lot of theorems in multivariables can be reduced by considering restrictions to lines and applying one-dimensional results.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong yes, I tried that but I don't see why the limit exists. I get $lim_{h->0}\frac{g(h)}{h}$ for $x_0 = 0$, but how does this help?

Comment: @buku That is not quite right if $h$ is a scalar, because $g(h)$ is not defined, since $g$ is defined on a disk. Instead take $h$ to be a vector and use norms; then you can estimate $|g(h)|/\|h\|$ for small vector $h$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong we don't have vectors until now :/